# Cheapest time a year to travel in Bali

Tags: budget, bali

I have the ability to travel all year round. What is the cheapest time to travel to Bali without the place being a ghost town?

Answer (score 3):

**February** is the quietest and thus cheapest time of the year in Bali: it's the rainy season and both the Christmas/NY peak and the Australian school holidays are over.

Over 5 million people live on the island, so it's never a "ghost town".